# Calling a function and passing it a return value from another function

Tags: windows, powershell

I have two function, but why do not they work together?

```
function OnlineADComputer {
    Get-ADComputer -filter {(enabled -eq "True") -and (operatingsystem -like "windows*") -and (operatingsystem -notlike "*server*")} -properties *|sort Name | % {
        $rtn = Test-Connection -CN $_.name -Count 1 -BufferSize 16 -Quiet
        IF($rtn -match 'True') {
            Return $_.dnshostname
          }
        }
}

function Get-LoggedIn {
    [CmdletBinding()]Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
        [string[]]$computername
    )
        ForEach ($pc in $computername){
            $logged_in = (gwmi Win32_ComputerSystem -Computer $pc).UserName
            $name = $logged_in.split("\")[1]
            "{0}: {1}" -f $pc,$name
    }
}
```

`Get-LoggedIn OnlineADComputer` - so does not work, why?

Comment: Those are not scripts but functions. In addition this would be more suitable for StackOverflow. With the call you're making you're passing the string "OnlineADComputer" to your function. Using Parenthesis could help to get a better scoping or using an intermediate variable for clarity.

Comment: maybe it works when you do `Get-LoggedIn (OnlineADComputer)`. But that's pretty ugly if you ask me. what about just doing `$computers = OnlineADComputer ; Get-LoggedIn $computers`

Comment: @SimonS I want to call a function for one computer and for all available on the network, but I do not want to write them with my hands, but I just want the function to be universal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run `Get-LoggedIn OnlineADComputer`, PowerShell interprets this as a call of `Get-LoggedIn` with an array of a single value, the literal text `OnlineADComputer`. We can prove this with some simpler functions:

```
Function Func1 { 
    'Hello!' 
}
Function Func2 { 
    [CmdletBinding()] Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string[]]$text
    ) 
    $text | % { $_.ToUpper() } 
}
```

`Func2 Func1` returns `FUNC1` - PowerShell was trying to be helpful by letting you write a string literal without quotes. You can make explicit that you want to call `Func1` by wrapping it in parentheses. `Func2 (Func1)` prints `HELLO!` as desired. Likewise, `Get-LoggedIn (OnlineADComputer)` should chain your functions as you want.

Interestingly, the syntax highlighting in the PowerShell console hints at the interpretation of your command. In the parentheses-less version, `Func1` is rendered in white and it is interpreted as text. In the parenthesized version, it is yellow and interpreted as a command.